# Unable to upload json file to aws cloudwatch

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to upload a json file on aws cloudwatch by replacing a content in it and in return I am uploading that file to cloudwatch.

Step 1:- I am saving a cloudwatch dashboard (in JSON format) using AWS cli (AWS cloudwatch get-dashboard *) on a windows machine.

Step2 :- replacing a content of a file and saves it as is.

Step3:- I am uploading newly modified file (in json) to cloudwatch but failed to upload.

when I view the file that doesn't show in a JSON format instead windows consider it as a string.

cli i am using as:

```
aws cloudwatch get-dashboard --dashboard-name SIT  --region eu-west-1 > SIT.json
```

output showing as below:

```
{
    "DashboardName": "SIT",
    "DashboardArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch::123456789:dashboard/SIT",
    "DashboardBody": "{\"widgets\":[{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"sit/Default\",\"Memory Available\",\"Instance\",\"i-04996767d0822cccf\"]]
,\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"title\":\"RT1 Available Memory\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":6,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"met
rics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-04996767d0822cccf\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"title\":\"RT1 CPU Utilization\",\"period\":300}},{\"ty
pe\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":18,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-092fcbe0dd0eeceb5\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\
"title\":\"SQL Primary CPU Utilization\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"y\":12,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilizati
on\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-045c7346c36f1cc3d\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"title\":\"Batch CPU Utilization\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":12,
\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"sit/Default\",\"Memory Available\",\"Instance\",\"i-045c7346c36f1cc3d\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"title\":\"Batch Available Me
mory\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"y\":18,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUU
tilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-092fcbe0dd0eeceb5\"]],\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"title\":\"SQL Secondary CPU Utilization\"}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":24,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":
{\"metrics\":[[\"sit/Default\",\"Memory Available\",\"Instance\",\"i-03b623e8400e4b801\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"title\":\"SAM Available Memory\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":
300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"y\":24,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-03b623e8400e4b801\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stack
ed\":false,\"title\":\"SAM CPU Utilization\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"y\":0,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"sit/Default\",\"Memor
y Available\",\"Instance\",\"i-0e82d201d3fac0d2d\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"title\":\"RT2 Available Memory\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"
y\":6,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-0e82d201d3fac0d2d\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"title\":\"RT2 CPU Utilizat
ion\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}}]}"
}
```

I tried using "ConvertTo-Json" but still failed to upload.

Error i am getting as follow;

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterInput) when calling the PutDashboard operation: The dashboard body is invalid, there are 1 validation errors: [ { "dataPath": "", "message": "Should have required property 'widgets'" } ]
```

Can someone advise?

Comment: What do you mean by "still no luck"? Did you get an error message? What did it say? Something different? Add this information to the question body, _do not add a comment_.

Comment: That means when i do "get-content SIT.json" it does show output as mentioned above which is not compatible with json viewer. Looks like powershell consider the whole output as a "string". How can i save the above output in json readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution using "format-list" powershell;

`Get-CWDashboard -DashboardName <SIT> | select DashboardBody | fl`

The above command will select only DashboardBody and format the output in a json view (original format of dashboard body).

With this i am now able to upload the DashboardBody back to cloudwatch dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Dashboardody` includes an escaped JSON object:

```
 "DashboardBody": "{\" ...
```

You can unescape the special characters in the following way:

```
$invalidJsonString = @'
{
    "DashboardName": "SIT",
    "DashboardArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch::123456789:dashboard/SIT",
    "DashboardBody": "{\"widgets\":[{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"sit/Default\",\"Memory Available\",\"Instance\",\"i-04996767d0822cccf\"]]
,\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"title\":\"RT1 Available Memory\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":6,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"met
rics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-04996767d0822cccf\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"title\":\"RT1 CPU Utilization\",\"period\":300}},{\"ty
pe\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":18,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-092fcbe0dd0eeceb5\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\
"title\":\"SQL Primary CPU Utilization\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"y\":12,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilizati
on\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-045c7346c36f1cc3d\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"title\":\"Batch CPU Utilization\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":12,
\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"sit/Default\",\"Memory Available\",\"Instance\",\"i-045c7346c36f1cc3d\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"title\":\"Batch Available Me
mory\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"y\":18,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUU
tilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-092fcbe0dd0eeceb5\"]],\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"title\":\"SQL Secondary CPU Utilization\"}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":0,\"y\":24,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":
{\"metrics\":[[\"sit/Default\",\"Memory Available\",\"Instance\",\"i-03b623e8400e4b801\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"title\":\"SAM Available Memory\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":
300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"y\":24,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-03b623e8400e4b801\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stack
ed\":false,\"title\":\"SAM CPU Utilization\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"y\":0,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"sit/Default\",\"Memor
y Available\",\"Instance\",\"i-0e82d201d3fac0d2d\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"title\":\"RT2 Available Memory\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"x\":12,\"
y\":6,\"width\":12,\"height\":6,\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"i-0e82d201d3fac0d2d\"]],\"view\":\"timeSeries\",\"stacked\":false,\"title\":\"RT2 CPU Utilizat
ion\",\"region\":\"eu-west-1\",\"period\":300}}]}"
}
'@

$correctedJsonString = (($invalidJsonString | % {[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)} ) -replace '"{', '{') -replace '}"', '}' 

$json = $correctedJsonString | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Output:

```
DashboardName DashboardArn                                DashboardBody
------------- ------------                                -------------
SIT           arn:aws:cloudwatch::123456789:dashboard/SIT @{widgets=System.Obj…
```

If you want to play around online you can use this TIO [link](https://tio.run/##vZdbT9swFMff/SmsiCkgtZBLSdtIkyiXSUxjY6SIB1JNrn3aekuTyHFvK/nsnRPG1qFQ0gvLS3yO7ePjX/4@deNoAiIZQBAsFns8HJOAs49JFHpS8LCP3@MTHc0RVo92TpJBNyKCfSZD0FyseZdtrfKsryXCrIuI0CWTxKVBNGITIunAdU3Lrh079UbTZU@jj4pCnEZslsWY@9qEsz7IxNfce2XJWQyq6WtDUNlRX6v42lQ5DPWe/X6rGXKg2qaljAHw/kAqy1FGLKIYhOSQhZs/Bclj3/tawuXROfTIKJB53CsYRmKGW2PCA9INIHdehokkIX00eNWoNZtO3akzo2FZlNKer3U6SHWNOUzyRCUfggciX1P51Wz6A5jq6pEgAeUR0OdRmI@FUXUCiaya@VDJZfC42Zu2@TcN/JhXPkTthkdZMNsw0rRSApCzLiC0RKh15x1dnFl50LPr21vJA/6TyDz9JTaXbBWdt4CjksHPsylig1bDMRtbyGdtOE2rR7tgMGYAUOgerwsHLUHwvn7C14IPiRJsEYwXOZZXUM5j9tTYNSX0soaOad2uOdR2eialNnsLDZ1m5am0il4RkVVB/7sIbYvoOYnlYoP@VJudimi9o1Z@K6vlhjY9lSVElJ1BD2gUssJTWE49Vq08F7Qb9dhdx7KhUTMMqHUbhrmFerzWVfEP1evSQeW1sw6j7cv0JnjQCj5vXZ53fgVCrwkIGhazDJPZPUINZm1Tfm7a1qYCKkcIbXQJ2kY/O6azLB@0pn46qYZSpJ8gtEcjIYBK@Pemv79f8AfgAb/D83tvlkgYHrZhKg9voD8KiLiYxgKSRK2cZC6Ydlz3NoSEkhj2974dpPgAVwXEAaGAdW2uV7A@15d9qZb5Uh2rjL6rFVUKhZk94LMoHKuP8kFEw2rWgdCd4BKqX0YyHkmcz0ZosfgF).

You can fix the invalid JSON content of your file via:

```
> ((Get-Content .\SIT.json | % {[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)} ) -replace '"{', '{') -replace '}"', '}' | out-file .\SIT.json

>  gc .\SIT.json | ConvertFrom-Json

DashboardName DashboardArn                                DashboardBody
------------- ------------                                -------------
SIT           arn:aws:cloudwatch::123456789:dashboard/SIT @{widgets=System.Object[]}
```

Comment: Thanks mate for this. I saved that output in filename as "SIT.json". Well, main problem is i am getting below error when i put dashboard in aws;

PS D:\Actimize\scripts> aws cloudwatch put-dashboard --dashboard-name SIT --dashboard-body file://SIT.json --region eu-west-1

An error occurred (InvalidParameterInput) when calling the PutDashboard operation: The dashboard body is invalid, there are 1 validation errors:
[
  {
    "dataPath": "",
    "message": "Should have required property 'widgets'"
  }
]
PS D:\XXXX\scripts>

Comment: When i save the file from cloudwatch on windows in json readable format and try to upload the same, it works.
for eg;
```
`{
            "type": "metric",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 6,
            "width": 12,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", "i-04996767d0822cccf" ]
                ],
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "stacked": false,
                "region": "eu-west-1",
                "title": "cpu utilisation"
            }`